# How to handle async code within a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I am reaching out to a SongKick's REST API in my ReactJS Application, using Axios.

I do not know how many requests I am going to make, because in each request there is a limit of data that I can get, so in each request I need to ask for a different page.

In order to do so, I am using a for loop, like this:

```
while (toContinue)
{
    axios.get(baseUrl.replace('{page}',page))
        .then(result => {
              ...
            if(result.data.resultsPage.results.artist === undefined)
                toContinue = false;
        });
    page++;
}
```

Now, the problem that I'm facing is that I need to know when all my requests are finished. I know about `Promise.All`, but in order to use it, I need to know the exact URLs I'm going to get the data from, and in my case I do not know it, until I get empty results from the request, meaning that the last request is the last one.

Of course that `axios.get` call is asynchronous, so I am aware that my code is not optimal and should not be written like this, but I searched for this kind of problem and could not find a proper solution.

Is there any way to know when all the async code inside a function is finished? 
Is there another way to get all the pages from a REST API without looping, because using my code, it will cause extra requests (because it is async) being called although I have reached empty results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code will crash the engine as the `while` loop will run forever as it never stops, the asynchronous requests are started but they will never finish as the thread is blocked by the loop.

To resolve that use `async` / `await` to wait for the request before continuing the loop, so actually the loop is not infinite:

```
async function getResults() {
 while(true) {
   const result = await axios.get(baseUrl.replace('{page}', page));
   // ...
   if(!result.data.resultsPage.results.artist)
     break;
 }
}
```